# Compile Windows Qt program on Linux , possible?

Tags: qt4, cross-platform, qt4.7

I wanted to cross-compile Window Qt-based program within my Linux , is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:
http://divided-mind.blogspot.com/2007/09/cross-compiling-qt4win-on-linux.html